# Python telebot как закрыть программу

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Вопрос по боту такой, как его закрыть???

использовал bot.stop_polling() вместе с exit(0) но он не выходит из программы. Запускаю через инфинити поллинг. Даже через критические ошибки не выбивает. Убивать процесс не хочется, но как закрыть программу? Хочу закрывать ее через присланную команду.

Comment: вы имеете в виду остановить бота или прекратить выполнять действия вызванные определённой командой через `/`?

Comment: закрыть программу впринципе, т.к. exit(0) не срабатывает